# httr: Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Failure when receiving data from the peer - FileSize?

Tags: r, curl, memory, fetch

I am httr:POST(ing) a login form to get into the website. To receive the data I am using the httr::GET:

```
GET("mock-url", user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible, MSIE 11, Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"))
```

Some URLs return 
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Failure when receiving data from the peer

If I do a similar request:

```
GET("mock-url",user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible, MSIE 11, Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"),write_disk("test.html",overwrite = T))
```

still some URLs return the same error as above, but the written file is complete and correct.

After some analysis I found that the cutoff file size is ~265KB.

Is there an additional header or other parameter that would solve the problem? A very similar webpage (but not as old) does not show this behavior.

Thank you